# validation engine ajax error 200 parsererror in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validation-engine

I want to do Existing Email Check with Validation Engine.But there is a problem showing in firebug console like below:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined index: reg_em

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 170

["email",true]

Ajax error: 200 parsererror

Here is my 
jquery.validationEngine-en.js:

```
"ajaxCheckEmail": {
                "url": base_url+"user/checkEmailExistence/",
                "extraDataDynamic": ['#reg_em'],
                "alertTextOk": "* This email is available",
                "alertText": "* This email is already taken",
                "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
            },
```

view of Email Field:

```
<input type="text" class="text_item_val_style validate[required,ajax[ajaxCheckEmail],custom[email]]" name="useremail" id="reg_em" style="height:21px;"/>
```

Controller:

function checkEmailExistence(){

```
   $email        = $_REQUEST['reg_em'];
   $getStatus = $this->users->existing_email_check($email);
   echo $getStatus;
```

}

Model:

```
function existing_email_check($email){
    $valid  = true;
    $rs     = $this->db->where('email', $email)->get('users');
    if($rs->num_rows() > 0){
        $valid  = false;
    }
    $rs->free_result();
    $arr    = array('email',$valid);
    return json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: if you do `$_REQUEST['reg_em']` then your fieldname should be reg_em, not your id. So do `$_REQUEST['useremail']` in your case. Thats maybe why the undefined index occurred.

Comment: [tag:jquery-validate] and [tag:jquery-validation-engine] are two totally different plugins.  Please be careful when tagging your question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this `$email = $_REQUEST['reg_em'];` write `$email = $_REQUEST['useremail'];`